# How would the data schema of bitcoin look like?

Tags: blockchain, database-schema, bitcoin

Since bitcoin is a blockchain and blockchain has been described as a kind of database, how would the data schema of bitcoin look like? Is it a single table database? If yes, which columns are inside this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The data is stored in an application-specific format optimized for compact storage, and wasn't really intended to be easily parsed by other applications.
> See https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/10814

For this custom format, see https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_documentation#block

[image: Block Format]

Answer (score 0):

There are various databases for various usages. As a reference client I would use bitcoin-core and describe its standard structure that is stored via the client. It actually uses *"leveldb"* and *"berkleydb-4.8"* for storing all kind of data.

### Wallet database

Saves your transactions, generated public/private keys. That is usually encrypted ;)

Source: [Wallets](https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/wallets.html)

### Index Database

It's usually OPTIONAL, but usually stores a list of all transactions and in which block they occurred

### Block Database

It's the most important db which locally stored and share via the network to communicate about newly created blocks and verify them. Every client has a copied version of it.

They usually store all blocks that ever occurred and also include fork-off blocks and also obsolete blocks.

Source: [Blockchain](https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/block_chain.html) / [Transactions](https://developer.bitcoin.org/devguide/transactions.html)

### Peers Database

Obviously there also is a database for all peers you have seen in the past. It rates each peer by giving it a ban-score, stores their IP addresses, ports and last seen status.

### Conclusion:

That would be all databases. They mostly have *"one table"* which includes exactly the previously described data structures.

More information about the [p2p network structure](https://developer.bitcoin.org/reference/p2p_networking.html) can be found right here.